# Measurement of the traffic generated by the packet source

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I'm working on resolving a statistical problem and I came across some difficulties.

The content of the task:

A measurement of the traffic generated by the packet source indicates that the average traffic is $\lambda$ [packets/s] and maximum traffic is $\sigma$ [packets/s]. The classic exponential distribution is not appropriate for modeling such a source of traffic, because the exponential distribution contains only one parameter (and two parameters were measured).

To model such a source of motion, you can use the shifted exponential distribution which is described by two parameters ($\gamma, \delta > 0$):
$$f(\tau) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & \tau<d \\ 
\gamma e^{-\gamma (\tau-d)} & \tau\geq d
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Random variable $\tau$ is the time interval between successive packets.

- Draw a distribution graph (1). What is the relationship between the maximum traffic  and $\delta$, for the distribution (#)?
- Designate a mean value of the distribution (#).
- Based on measurements of traffic sources $(\lambda, \sigma)$ select firstly $\delta$ parameter for distribution (#), then $\gamma$ parameter for distribution (#).

So far I've managed to solve the subsection 2. and this is what I've came up with:
[my solution to subsection 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MYri.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Part 1 is simple.  If $\delta$ is the minimum interarrival time for consecutive packets, where time is measured in seconds, then at most $1/\delta$ packets can arrive in one second.  For instance, if $\delta = 0.01$ seconds, meaning that we are assured that the time between packets is at least $0.01$ seconds, then the most packets we can observe in one second is $1/0.01 = 100$ packets, and this is $\sigma$.  So $$\sigma \delta = 1.$$

For Part 3, use what you know from Parts 1 and 2 to establish a relationship between $\lambda$ and $\gamma$.  The average traffic intensity $\lambda$ is simply the average you found in Part 2.  Solve for $\gamma$ in terms of $\lambda$ and $\sigma$.